# Android minSdkVersion confusion

Tags: android

I have an App which has minSdkVersion defined to 19. I am still able to install an exported APK to a device which has Android 4.0 or 4.1. Is this behavior correct and the minSdkVersion will only be used by the play store to filter out irrelevant devices?

Comment: "Is this behavior correct" -- no. I suspect that your APK has a lower `minSdkVersion` than what you are thinking it has. Try running `aapt dump badging /path/to/your.apk`, where `aapt` will be in one of your SDK's `build-tools/` subdirectories (e.g., `build-tools/23.0.1/`).

Comment: go to file-> project structure -> app-> flavors -> check minSDK version is it correct?

Comment: The aapt dump command indeed showed that it was set to 14. Thank you!